# Проверка строки на empty

Tags: java, строки

Как проверить строку на пустоту? Если есть например строка '     '(между кавычками несколько пробелов), то метод isEmpty() возвращает false. Писать свой метод, или есть готовые решения?

Answer (score 3):

Есть готовый библиотечный метод `org.junit.platform.commons.util.StringUtils.isBlank(String)`, который при ближайшем рассмотрении выглядит вот так:

```
public static boolean isBlank(String str) {
    return str == null || str.trim().isEmpty();
}
```

т.е., еще и на `null` проверяет.

Comment: c java 11 `isBlank` есть уже у самого `String`

Answer (score 2):

Для строк в Java используются двойные кавычки.
Пустая строка не содержит никаких символов:

```
"".isEmpty(); //true
```

Пробелы можно обрезать методом `trim()`:

```
"    ".trim().isEmpty(); //true
```

Этот метод возвращает новую строку, в которой удалены пробелы из начала исходной строки и из её конца:

```
String t = " hello world    ".trim(); //"hello world"

"hello world".equals(t); //true
```